# C++ public method definitions after class definition?

Tags: c++, oop, variables, inheritance

```
class Car {

    private:
      int doors;

    public: 
      void print();
      Car();
      Car(int doors);
 };


 Car :: Car (int doors) 
 {
     doors = doors;
 }
```

Is this the proper syntax for a class definition in C++?

Why are methods (in the examples that I've seen) declared outside of the class defintion?

What does the :: syntax really mean?

Comment: 1. yes 2. To remove class implementation from the header 3. Look up "scope resolution operator".

Comment: 2. For the same reason that functions in C are usually declared in a header but defined separately in a .c file (but note the member functions are _declared_ in the class definition, and _defined_ outside it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. it is valid.

Methods are not "declared" outside. They are "defined" outside to make the declaration and definition separate. You have included the declaration inside your class, which states their membership. You can include the definition inside as well for most of them. However, class implementations are usually done in separate implementation files.

The :: is called the scope resolution operator. "Car :: Car (int doors)" means "the constructor Car from the class Car that takes an int parameter"

Edit: Just to add, the scope resolution operator identifies which scope (in your example, which class) the artifact (in your example, the constructor) belongs to.

Comment: thanks, great answer. this is kind of an obvious question (i hope) that i would like confirmation on, but are you able to call various constructors with the same name and define them using the scope resolution operator and difference class names?

Comment: @user: A constructor must have the same name as the class, therefore you cannot define two constructors of the "same name" under two different classes. A single class may have multiple overloaded constructors under the same name, but with different parameters.

But if it is for any other function, yes, you can define functions with same name under different classes in the same file using the scope resolution operator. If those functions are static, you can even call them separately using the scope resolution operator.

Comment: Ok, yes, this is what I meant, other functions other than the constructor. Thank you for your thorough answer.